# Change Android Studio download path

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to update my Android SDK at work at I'm getting errors like

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp\usb_driver_r09-windows.zip (Access is denied)
```

It believe it's a firewall issue, and I think it's permissions issue, (I don't have access to sdk/temp).

Can I change the download path so it downloads to `C:/Documents And Settings/MyUser/etc...`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Administrator rights, you won't be able to update an Android SDK that's located in **C:\Program Files**, as this one is; it's not only a matter of where the files are downloaded. You'll either have to get your administrator to run Android Studio and update the SDK, or you can reinstall Android Studio for your user account only.

Comment: If I can get Admin to give me full rights to `C:\Program Files\Android` and everything inside should I be able to update it then? Or would I need other rights to get it to install?